# Extracting item from a list stored as string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, series

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': '[2,3,4,5,6' }, {'a': 10, 'b': '[54,3,40,5'}] 
test = pd.DataFrame(data) 
display(test)

    a     b
0   1   [2,3,4,5,6
1   10  [54,3,40,5
```

I want to list the number in column b, but as the list has the [ only at the beginning, doesnt allow me to create the list, I'm trying to remove the "[" so I can extract the numbers, but I keep getting errors, what I'm doing wrong?

This is how the numbers are stored

`test.iloc[1,1]`

```
'[54,3,40,5'
```

And this is what I've tried to remove the "[".

```
test.iloc[0,1].replace("[",'', regex=True).to_list()

test.iloc[0,1].str.replace("[\]\[]", "")
```

What i want to achieve is to have b as a proper list so i can apply other functions.

```
    a     b
0   1   [2,3,4,5,6]
1   10  [54,3,40,5]
```

Comment: When did you get the error, while replacing the character or converting to list?

Comment: You cannot convert a string to list directly using to_list()

Comment: try this, ```pd.eval(test['b'] + "]")``` or ```test.b.str.replace(r"[", "").str.split(",")```

Comment: You can try this `test['b'] = test['b'].str.findall(r'\d+')`

Answer (score 1):

To make your `'b'` column a list you can first delete the open squared bracket at the beginning, and then use the `split` method on each element of your `'b'` column

```
test['b'] = test['b'].str.replace('[', '').map(lambda x: x.split(','))

test
#     a            b
# 0   1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# 1  10  [54, 3, 40, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
def func(col):
  return eval(col+']')

test['b'] = test['b'].apply(func)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: i add ']' in a string and call function eval() to convert string to object

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': '[2,3,4,5,6' }, {'a': 10, 'b': '[54,3,40,5'}] 
test = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(test['b'][0][1:])
for i in range(len(test['b'])):
    test['b'][i] = test['b'][i][1:]
```

[image: here is the result]